# MANIFEST "invalid header file" for multi line class-path

Tags: java, manifest

Maybe I missing something.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/concar.jar lib/ini4j-0.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar lib/javadbf-0.4.0.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/spring-asm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-beans-3.2.0.M1.jar
lib/spring-context-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-context-support-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-core-3.2.0.M1.jar 
lib/spring-expression-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-orm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-oxm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-test-3.2.0.M1.jar 
lib/spring-tx-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-web-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.M1.jar 
lib/spring-ws-1.5.9-all.jar lib/swingx-1.6.1.jar lib/troughoasis.jar
Main-Class: mypackage.com.IniClass
```

At the end of java jar creation procces I got this error: "Invalid header file"

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the answer but Two spaces before to start a new line at "Class-Path" resolves the problem.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/concar.jar lib/ini4j-0.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
  lib/javadbf-0.4.0.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/spring-asm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-beans-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-context-3.2.0.M1.jar 
  lib/spring-context-support-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-core-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-expression-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-orm-3.2.0.M1.jar
  lib/spring-oxm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-test-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-tx-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-web-3.2.0.M1.jar
  lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-ws-1.5.9-all.jar lib/swingx-1.6.1.jar lib/troughoasis.jar 
Main-Class: mypackage.com.IniClass
```